# Cognos 10 Report Studio: total amount using auto sum is not matching with the amount calculated by total function

Tags: report, cognos

I am using Report Studio to create some simple business reports.
I faced one problem where the total of the report using auto sum function and calculation using total function is no matching. I'd appreciate if you could help me find out why this is happening, and how I can fix this.

THis is kind of an invoice report, and I have a list showing details and also showing only the total figure inserted in different area of report.

List shows like below. Columns `AMOUNT, SVC CHARGE, TOTAL` are calculated values. Sum of the total showing 43,122.56 using auto sum (sigma icon). 
Now, I have to put only the grand total seperate part on the same report (outside this list, but inserted as singleton/tex item.) First, I tried to pull this Total(TOTAL) into the text item, but showed figure 43,122.96 which has discrepancy of 0.4. Also, I tried to insert calculation  `Total ([Total(AMOUNT)]+[Total(SVC CHARGE)] for report)` but also resulted in value 43,122.96. I want to have the amount same as grand total on list 43,122.56 but cannot.....Appreciate your help! Thank you!

```
Order # Quantity      RATE      AMOUNT  SVC CHARGE       TOTAL
A         41.268    $26.00   $1,072.97      160.12   $1,233.09
B         56.976    $26.00   $1,481.38      221.07   $1,702.45
C         72.87     $26.00   $1,894.62      282.74   $2,177.36
C        213.66     $26.00   $5,555.16      829      $6,384.16
D        480.24     $26.00  $12,486.24     1863.33  $14,349.57
E        185.172    $30.00   $5,555.16      718.47   $6,273.63
F        183.036    $30.50   $5,582.60      710.18   $6,292.78
G         45.147    $23.50   $1,060.95      175.17   $1,236.12
H        126.859    $23.50   $2,981.19      492.21   $3,473.40
Grand total                 $37,670.27     5452.29  $43,122.56

AMOUNT : _round ([RATE]*[QUANTITY],2)               
SVC CHARGE : _round ([RATE]*[QUANTITY],2)               
TOTAL: [AMOUNT]+[SVC CHARGE]
```

Comment: Which total is correct? Once you have established what the right number should be then you can work backward to isolate the discrepancy. Have you tried changing your manual aggregate to total([Amount] + [SVC Charge] for report)? The one you have totals each column independently and then totals the totals. This may be compounding rounding discrepancies.

Comment: Dont use round, just format the output to 2 decimals in design view. I'd bet its related to that. I'd work this out in Excel to prove but your SVC_CHARGE formula is the same as AMOUNT.